# Cannot Unpickle my model after Reinstalling Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I used pickle for a few months to save my ML-models and was able to load them without any problems but recently after Reinstalling Windows and Python I am getting this error message when I try to load the exact same model:

`AttributeError: type object 'sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.NeighborsHeap' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'`

Does anyone know what is causing this?

I used Python 3.6 (64bit) before and I am using the same one right now.

Comment: Same before and after, Python 3.6 (64 bit).

Comment: What are the versions of sklearn and requirements? Try installing an older sklearn?

Comment: That is a possibility, is there a way to check version requirements of the model object?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you are using a different version of `sklearn`.

According to [search results for `__reduce_cython__` in Cython's codebase](https://github.com/cython/cython/search?q=__reduce_cython__), it's added by Cython to some compiled types to make [`__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=__reduce__#object.__reduce__) work correctly or something. So its absense likely means changes in the affected classes or their hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, how can I fix this problem? Should I downgrade or upgrade? How do I find the required version?

Comment: @Tartaglia With https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickletools.html , you can see the interpretation of pickled data. There might be something hinting on the version there. Otherwise, by trial and error. E.g. you have the file's date; with that, you may recall a rough time period when you installed the module -- look up which version was the latest at that time.